# Download object performance for Jclouds swift client

Tags: object, openstack, openstack-swift, jclouds

Download object performance for jclouds java swift client is much slower than the python swiftclient api. I am using the blobstore api for jclouds. 
For download of a 8GB object,I tried :

```
 Blob blob = blobStore.getBlob("container", "object");
 InputStream in = blob.getPayload().getInput();
 File targetFile = new File("filepath");
 FileUtils.*copyInputStreamToFile*(in, targetFile);
```

Download time using jclouds: >1 hour
Download time using Python swift client api : 4 minutes

Is there any parameter/config which I am missing ? Is there any other way I can read the file ?